# How to make this more readable with many if else

Tags: c#

Let me just say this right off the bat: **If-Else** is often a poor choice.
It leads to complicated designs, less readable code, and may be pain inducing to refactor.

The objective of this method is to make a panel in green color if the candidate has exceeded a volume and if he has spoken in a non-stop manner greater than two seconds of silence.
The panel become red if a candidate is speaking, then it stops without reaching the minimum second threshold to talk or we have a silence about suddenly I want to write this method in another way so that it is more readable and easy to understand.

**Here is the code :**

```
private Stopwatch stopSpeach = new Stopwatch();
private Stopwatch startSpeach = new Stopwatch();
bool startTimer = false;

void SoundInput()
{
    if (VolumeMicro > NumVolume_Minimum.Value)
    {
        if (startTimer)
        {
            stopSpeech.Restart();
        }
        else
        {
            startTimer = true;
            startSpeech.Restart();
            stopSpeech.Restart();
        }
    }
    else if (startTimer && stopSpeech.ElapsedMilliseconds > numericUpDown_WaitStop.Value)
    {
        if (panel_Timer.BackColor != Color.Red)
        {
            SetInfoPanel(Color.Red);
        }
        startTimer = false;
    }


    if (startTimer && startSpeech.ElapsedMilliseconds > numericUpDown_WaitStart.Value)
    {
        if (panel_Timer.BackColor != Color.Green && stopSpeech.ElapsedMilliseconds < 100)
            SetInfoPanel(Color.Green);

        if (VolumeMicro > NumVolume_Maximum.Value && panel_Timer.BackColor != Color.Green)
            SetInfoPanel(Color.Orange);
    }
}
```

I thought about getting rid of the previous code and using a **dictionary** :

```
  public void PerformOp(string operationName)
    {
        var operations = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
        operations["green"] = () => { SetInfoPanel(Color.Green); };
        operations["red"] = () => { SetInfoPanel(Color.Red); };
        operations["orange"] = () => { SetInfoPanel(Color.Red); };
        operations[operationName].Invoke();
    }
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Speach like, speech?

Comment: (Have a spelling checker help you.)

Comment: @Reinderien yes

Comment: I would recommend you to always use braces `{}` where you can, even if your `if`s body only contains one line of code. It just makes the entire code more readable and consistent.

Comment: I would say that this is a procedural approach. You might want to consider switching to an object-oriented approach. Maybe make a `Speech` class with methods like `Start()`, `Stop()` and `Elapsed()` and an `InfoPanel` class with a method like `SetColor(speechTime)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought about getting rid of the previous code and using a dictionary

I have no idea how the second snippet is a rewrite of the first snippet. There is no contextual overlap whatsoever. But I'll review both snippets independently.

---

### Snippet 2

```
public void PerformOp(string operationName)
{
    var operations = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
    operations["green"] = () => { SetInfoPanel(Color.Green); };
    operations["red"] = () => { SetInfoPanel(Color.Red); };
    operations["orange"] = () => { SetInfoPanel(Color.Red); };
    operations[operationName].Invoke();
}
```

What you have here is a `switch`. This is in essence a "multiple `if`".

```
public void PerformOp(string operationName)
{
    switch(operationName)
    {
        case "green":
            SetInfoPanel(Color.Green);
            break;
        case "orange":
            SetInfoPanel(Color.Orange);
            break;
        case "red":
            SetInfoPanel(Color.Red);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception($"Unknown operation name: ${operationName}");
}
```

This achieves the same thing, without having to resort to a dictionary.

However, there is still some things to review here.

- Notice how I added a `default` case to deal with unknown values. You should let the caller know when they use a bad value, instead of silently doing nothing (unless it makes contextual sense to do so).
- Since you're dealing with a closed set of operation names, an enum would be relevant here.

```
public enum OperationType { Green, Orange, Red };

public void PerformOp(OperationType operationType)
{
    switch(operationType)
    {
        case OperationType.Green:
            SetInfoPanel(Color.Green);
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

- But then you realize that you're really just mapping one enum (`OperationType`) to another (`Color`). Maybe that's what you need here, if you want to strictly keep it do just those three colors and not every possible `Color` value. However, if any possible `Color` value goes, then you can simply cut out the middle man:

```
public void PerformOp(Color color)
{
    SetInfoPanel(color);
}
```

- But at this point, there seems to be little purpose to the `PerformOp` method itself, no?

---

### Snippet 1

The problem with this code is that it is very complex. You've broken a complex problem down into its constituent parts, but you've made no effort to describe the separate parts, which makes it impossible to follow.

For the life of me, I don't understand what your code tries to achieve. I understand individual lines and evaluations, but not how one relates to another, and what the overall goal here is. For the sake of example, I'm going to invent descriptions here, to show you how you could've made this easier to parse. Obviously, rename them to suit your specific scenario.

Whenever you're dealing with a non-trivial evaluation, try to store it in a boolean value that describes what it expresses. For example:

```
bool currentPlaybackExceedsUpperLimit = startTimer && stopSpeech.ElapsedMilliseconds > numericUpDown_WaitStop.Value;

if (currentPlaybackExceedsUpperLimit)
{
    if (panel_Timer.BackColor != Color.Red)
    {
        SetInfoPanel(Color.Red);
    }
    startTimer = false;
}
```

The first `if` was complex, but now I can easily read what that evaluation means in human terms. The second `if`, however, is trivially readable, so there was no point to adding a boolean variable to describe it any further.

In some cases, it makes sense to further separate the evaluations from the logic, and start using separate class methods/properties for this. Since you're dealing with a chain of operations here, that seems a valid reason to do so.

As a second step, you can then also separate the actual resulting logic from the decision tree which decides what should be done. This means that you separate your monolith method into three different parts:

- The logic for evaluating the current state (= the `if` evaluations)
- The logic for mutating the current state (= the `if` bodies)
- The decision logic (= the `if` structure itself)

The principle is the same as before, but instead of using a variable, you can also use a class method/property. The whole method could be rewritten as:

```
// The logic for evaluating the current state (= the `if` evaluations)

private bool VolumeIsTooLoud => VolumeMicro > NumVolume_Minimum.Value;

private bool CurrentPlaybackExceedsUpperLimit =>
          startTimer 
          && stopSpeech.ElapsedMilliseconds > numericUpDown_WaitStop.Value;

private bool CurrentPlaybackIsInProgress =>
          startTimer 
          && startSpeech.ElapsedMilliseconds > numericUpDown_WaitStart.Value;

// The logic for mutating the current state (= the `if` bodies)

private void RestartSpeech()
{
    if (!startTimer)
    {
        startTimer = true;
        startSpeech.Restart();
    } 
        
    stopSpeech.Restart();
}

private void FinishPlayback()
{
    if (panel_Timer.BackColor != Color.Red)
    {
        SetInfoPanel(Color.Red);
    }
    startTimer = false;
}

private void ShowCurrentState()
{
    if (panel_Timer.BackColor != Color.Green 
        && stopSpeech.ElapsedMilliseconds < 100)
    {
        SetInfoPanel(Color.Green);
    }

    if (VolumeMicro > NumVolume_Maximum.Value 
        && panel_Timer.BackColor != Color.Green)
    {
        SetInfoPanel(Color.Orange);
    }
}

// The decision logic (= the `if` structure itself)

void SoundInput()
{
    if (VolumeIsTooLoud)
    {
        RestartSpeech();
    }
    else if (CurrentPlaybackExceedsUpperLimit)
    {
        FinishPlayback();
    }

    if (CurrentPlaybackIsInProgress)
    {
        ShowCurrentState();
    }
}
```

There are probably further improvements to be done here, but they require a more contextual understanding of the code, and I don't quite understand the specifics going on here.

However, I hope this example makes it clear that by separating your code into smaller chunks that are more easily digestible and are clearly named, you can make significant improvements to the code's readability and maintainability.